# Libcurl - cookie authentication

Tags: c++, libcurl

I want to avoid using the file system when using cookies with Libcurl...is that possible?  It seems the documentation and examples all require the use of writing and reading cookies from files...maybe I'm wrong.

So far I'm doing something like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postfield);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURL_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, userpass);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

//writes the cookie to file sent from server
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILENAME);

curl_easy_perform(curl);

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cookie_interface.html That prints cookies and edits them as well without the use of the file system.

I've used that example myself to do the whole cookie modification thing.

Also useful that's not in the example:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "name=xxx; name2=xxx;");
```

Comment: updated my original post. Both examples you provide create the cookie in the code itself...I want to save the cookie sent back from the server (but not in a file).